# amplify graphql auth rules with identityClaim not working after push

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

after a push our auth rules with identityClaim are not working anymore.
We did not update these or the values that are checked. We just added some new indexes etc.

group claims are working fine.

We tryed updating auth and api

Anyone got suggestions what may be wrong here?